# Can you add to a Github pull request after the source repo is deleted?

Tags: github

I've opened a pull request (PR) on a repo, but then managed to accidentally delete the branch I initiated the request from. The maintainer of the project has requested I make a couple changes.. now I'm stuck.

Github still has the PR, but now shows the source of the branch as "unknown repository".

I was able to recover the exact commit and re-push that (it has the same commit hash as the commit in the PR), but it still shows as "unknown repository".

Is there a way to push directly into the PR itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the steps [outlined in this issue](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/198#issuecomment-147059582) to pull the the branch from the PR:

> So to update a PR, even if you have removed the original remote branch out of which the PR was created, you just need to:
>
> - Fetch the PR (`git fetch pull/<id>/head:branchname` and `git checkout branchname`).
> - Add new commits, amend, rebase, do whatever you like.
> - Push or push force (`git push remote +branch`).
>
> And after that the PR will be automagically updated :)

[This support page](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally) also talks about how to recreate a branch from a PR, although it ends with creating a new PR (so worst case you could grab the old branch, then close that PR and open a new one).